# Delphi Component Disappears from Component Palette in new Data Module

Tags: delphi, activex, datamodule

The declaration of my component is:

```
MyComponentX = class(TActiveXComponent, IspdInterfaceX)
```

TActivexComponent:

```
TActiveXComponent = class(TActiveXControl, IOleControl)
```

When I open a new DataModule in any Delphi version, the component disappears from the Component Palette.

I try to change the ClassGroup in Delphi XE2, but this don't works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data modules can only host non-visual controls, and `TActiveXControl` is not a non-visual control.

You ask what is the definition of non-visual control. According to [this article](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20569), the definition is that if the component is derived from `TComponent` and not derived from `TControl`, then it is a non-visual control.

That said, the inheritance hierarchy for `TActiveXControl` is: `TObject`, `TComObject`, `TTypedComObject`, `TAutoObject`, `TActiveXControl`. So I am at something of a loss at to why it ever appears on your component palette since it is not derived from `TComponent`. It would be interesting to know how you registered it. All the same, it's not a non-visual component in the meaning of the act.

Comment: The answer now covers that

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can create a class wrapper to use your ActiveX in this data module.

```
TWrapper = class(TComponent)
private
    FYourActiveX: TYourActiveX;
public
    procedure Method;
end;

procedure TWrapper.Method;
begin
    FYourActiveX.Method;
end;
```